# Can't retrieve value from template field

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to get value from my templatefield for my ID which is in gridview.

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("cr_Id") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I need to retrieve this ID to update it. Following are codes from aspx.cs

```
 GridView myGrid = (GridView)sender; // the gridview
        Label lblProdId = (Label)myGrid.FindControl("lblID");
        string colID = lblProdId.ToString(); 

BLLCredentials updateID = new BLLCredentials();
            int ds;
            ds = updateID.updStatus(colID, 1);
            gv_CredentialsList.EditIndex = -1;
            Bind();
            sendEmail();
```

the error is

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request.

Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

Comment: In which way you trying to get `lblID` value in `aspx.cs` page. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: if this ItemTemplate is in your datacontrol (i.e. gridview,datalist,repeater), you can get lblID value using databind event of respective control. In databind event, you need to find control on each binding using FindControl property. This databind event refer to RowDataBound for Gridview, ItemDataBound for Repeater and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a control inside GridView Itemtemplate like

```
Label lblProdId = (Label )myGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("lblID");
```

Rows[Put your row index] And Cells[Put your cell index]